# jQuery 1.9 doesn't bubble file select/change event in old Firefox

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling, file-io, jquery-1.9

As of jQuery 1.9, the file select change event doesn't bubble / propagate anymore in old Firefox.  It was fine in jQuery 1.8, but it stopped working in jQuery 1.9.

Here is an example:

```
<ul class="result"></ul>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="file_input" name="file" type="file" />
</div>
<script>
$('.wrapper').on('change', '.file_input', function() {
    $('.result').append('<li>file selected</li>');
});
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle using jQuery 1.8 that demonstrates how I expect the behavior to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/UMxkt/

In all browsers (including Firefox 3.6), every time I select a file, the change event on the input[type=file] element bubbles.

Here's the same example using jQuery 1.9.  Using Firefox 3.6, the change event no longer bubbles.   It seems to work fine in Firefox 18+ though:

http://jsfiddle.net/UMxkt/1/

**This leads me to 2 questions:**

1) What version of Firefox does this stop working?

2) Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Did you try the way of jquery migration?
Using an older jquery version but make working the new version:
 https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Answer (score 2):

i ran into this problem today and figured out that the way they detect browser features for change event bubbling is broken for older versions of firefox.  [Bug 13609](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13609) was submitted and then closed because jQuery does not support old versions of firefox

**Edit**

after getting to work and testing with IE8 a bunch, i came up with the following as probably the most compatible solution. you can see my revisions to see how i ended up with this as my workaround. This should be executed after loading jQuery 1.9 and later

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // checks taken from jQuery 1.8.3
    function isChangeBubbleSupported(element) {
        if (!element.attachEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        var eventName = { change: true };
        if (eventName in element) {
            return true;
        }

        element.setAttribute(eventName, "return;");
        return typeof div[eventName] === "function";
    }

    var div = document.createElement(div);
    if (window.onchange === undefined && isChangeBubbleSupported(div)) {
        // setting this to undefined will prevent special case handling for change events
        // that was breaking old versions of firefox
        jQuery.event.special.change = undefined;
    }
    div = null;
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UMxkt/14/

Answer (score 1):

Interesting find,

As far as your first question, I don't know the answer, the only way I can think of to figure that out is to go through and try to find as many FireFox versions as possible testing to identify when the issue occurred.  Though I did find a Firefox version archive http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

If your `.file_input` element is not created dynamically you could do something like this:

```
$('.file_input').change(function(){
   $('.result').append('<li>file selected</li>');    
});
```

I worked with the code for a while to see if I could come up with a work around that uses event delegation. I found that while `.change` does not work in firefox 3.6 and jQuery 1.9 `.click` however does.

I came up with the following:

```
var file = '';
var selected = false;
var tid; 
function fileCheck() {
    if(file != $('.file_input').val())
    {
        file = $('.file_input').val();
        $('.result').append('<li>file selected</li>');
        selected = false;
        clearInterval(tid);
    }
}
$('.wrapper').on('click','.file_input',function(){  
   clearInterval(tid);
   selected = true;
   tid = setInterval(fileCheck, 300); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMxkt/2/)

<s>**Update**</s>

It seemingly does not work when referencing the file input by `class` or `id` using event delegation, but referencing it other ways works. Such as:

```
$('.wrapper input[type=file]').on('change', function() {
    $('.result').append('<li>file selected</li>');
});
```

Comment: In your *Update*, you're not using event delegation, as you're attaching the event listener to the element directly.  In such a case, any selector (even class or id) will work.

Comment: @JohnnyO Right, I guess its the same thing as referencing it directly.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the polling technique, but I'll give you the bounty as it's the best answer offered here.  For anyone who wants to use this technique, you should consider the problem that this will introduce.  When the file dialog appears, click 'Cancel' or select the same file that was already selected.  The polling never stops and will continue indefinitely.

Comment: @JohnnyO When looking into your question I was thinking about how I might avoid the `infinite polling` in cases of `cancel` I thought of setting a timer to cancel the polling after a minute or so if nothing had happened.  But then again someone might open up the file picker go afk for a while and then select a file so I didn't go with it..  I don't know that I thought of the `same file that was already selected` case before, though it would have been covered.  Good Eye and Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code instead:

```
$('.wrapper input:first-child').on('change', function() {
$('.result').append('<li>file selected</li>');
});
```

Comment: You're not using event delegation (aka bubbling/propagation), as you're attaching the event listener to the element directly.